# Character thrown but integer catched: how are promotions and conversions handled with exceptions?

Tags: c++, try-catch

I'm programming some exercises about exceptions in C++ with NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1 on Windows 10 using MinGW 64 bits, but the expected result is not the same when I execute the code in IDE.

Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f() { 
   throw 'A';
}

int main() {
   try { 
      try { 
         f();
      } catch (int) { 
         cout << "In catch (int) 1" << endl;
         throw;
      } catch (...) {
         cout << "In catch (...) 1" << endl;
         throw 65;
      }
   } catch (int&) {
           cout << "In catch (int&)" << endl;
   } catch (int) {
           cout << "In catch (int) 2" << endl;
   } catch (const int) {
           cout << "In catch (const int)" << endl;
   } catch (...) {
           cout << "In catch (...) 2" << endl;
   }

   cout << "End of program" << endl;
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The terminal displays this :

```
In catch (int) 1
In catch (int&)
End of program
```

Normally, the terminal should display in the first line "In catch(...) 1", but I don't understand why the IDE doesn't display the good result.

I tried this code with g++ on PowerShell, same result, but with g++ on Linux Ubuntu, he displays the right result.

I don't have any suggestions.

Thank you for your help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Integral promotions](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#1) are considered when a suitable catch is searched for. `'A'` is a character literal and is promoted to an `int`.

Thus:

1. `throw 'A';` is performed;
2. `catch (int)` after integral promotion;
3. `throw;` rethrows the same object ([no copy is made](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw));
4. `catch (int&)` catches it (note: `catch (int)` could catch it but it is not the *nearest catch*);
5. program ends.

For your information, `[except.throw]/2` explains what *nearest* means:

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (`[except.handle]`);
>   “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following the try keyword
>   was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an implementation issue, because the behavior cannot be reliably reproduced even with MinWGW on Windows, depending on the version.  In theory, there is [no conversion or promotion of the base types in the catch(..) block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch), only a user-defined class can be converted to a base class.

The question mentions the "right result" because in theory (and on most architectures tried), throw(char) cannot be caught by catch(int) but only by catch(...).  Still, there is no clear explanation why this is not so in some cases.